# PHP redirect with form values and Google Analytics session

Tags: php, html

http://www.spiritofphiladelphia.com/  -> view of the form

The form on the right hand side of the page needs to be tweaked somewhat. 
I need to redirect the user to a different page along with the form values and Google Analytics tracking code depending on the size of the Party. Their are only two possible choices to choose for the party size.

I thought it would be simple, just collect the form values in an array and pass them through using `header()`. That was before I realized I need to keep track of the users session as well. 
I've never written a script to use `session()` data, or how to retrieve the data I need.

Please help this front-end developer who has avoided scripting of any code due to lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$city = $_POST['metro']; 
$product = $_POST['product'];
$event = $_POST['tod'];
$date = $_POST['cruiseDate'];
$party = $_POST['pax'];

if($party == '1-19'){
    header("Location:url/contact-us?rfp[date]=$date&amp;$event");
}
elseif($party == '30-74'){
    $data = http_build_query($_POST);
    header("Location:url.com/search/?".$data);  
}
```

This ended up doing exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read through a simple tutorial for PHP (such as w3schools).
You need to learn how to use forms with $_POST, and how to handle the $_SESSION array.

It is a bit to big and general to answer here. Go through the Basic chapter in this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp
or here:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

That will get you up and running with PHP in a couple of hours. You won't regret it!

Comment: I second that. Especially as a front-ender.

Comment: I've read through the W3schools info before. I just needed to get my hands dirty with the code.